# Django datefield javascript

Tags: javascript, django, datefield

Im trying to add a [dropdown datepicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker) to my date field in my django project. And this is how I have set it up

In `forms.py` -

```
self.fields['start_date'] = forms.DateField(
                widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
            )
```

In my `base.html` which is my base template I imported the relevant files -

On top:

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css"
        rel="stylesheet">
```

and on the bottom I have

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<script src="{% static "js/icheck/icheck.min.js" %}"></script>

<script src="{% static "js/custom.js" %}"></script>

<!-- pace -->
<script src="{% static "js/pace/pace.min.js" %}"></script>
{% block scripting %}{% endblock %}
</body>

</html>
```

In my template where the form is generated:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class='input-group date'>
        {{ form.start_date }}
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and on the bottom of the template I have:

```
    {% block scripting %}
        <script type=application/javascript>
           #tooltip function which works great
        </script>

        <script type=application/javascript>
            $('.input-group.date').datepicker({
            });
        </script>
    {% endblock %}
```

This generates the field as i want - [image: startdate]. However the drop down does not work. I cant seem to figure out why. I tried a [codepen](http://codepen.io/isharief318/pen/vGVbxE?editors=1010) and it works flawlessly. Can someone help me in figuring out what the issue might be??

Comment: Any error in the console ?

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError:$ is not defined` . It shows up for both the `js` functions ( on chrome - developer tools )

Answer (score 1):

Ensure the custom scripts block:

```
{% block scripting %}
{% endblock %}
```

comes last in your `base.html`. In that way, `jQuery` and others would be loaded then your custom scripts

Comment: Funny thing is. I do not have any `block script` defined in my base.html. yet the tooltip js works

Comment: Is the form's template extending `base.html`?

Comment: Yes the first line in my template is `extends base.html`

Comment: ok `{% extends 'base.html' %}`, you mean. Your `base.html` should have a block like the one I have posted (placed at the bottom, for reasons already stated) which will be used for scripts (as you have done) by templates extending the base

Comment: Yes I have it like yu said. I edited my question to show what the bottom of my `base.html` looks like

Comment: another check: try removing `type=application/javascript` from the script tag

Comment: Ok I changed the script to `<script>
            $('.input-group-addon').datepicker({
            });
        </script>` . i can finally see the calender popup. But clicking on any date doesnt show up in the field

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112437/discussion-between-moses-koledoye-and-newkid101).